# Create a column indicating the presence of a value in a set of columns

Tags: r, data.table

I have a table looks like this:

```
table1 <- data.table(ID = 1:10,
                     col1 = c("x1", "x2", "x3", NA, NA, NA, "x7", "x8", "x9", "x10"),
                     col2 = c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", NA, NA, "x7", NA, "x9", "x10"),
                     col3 = c("x1", NA, NA, "x4", "x5", "x6", NA, "x8", NA, "x10"))

    ID col1 col2 col3
 1:  1   x1   x1   x1
 2:  2   x2   x2 <NA>
 3:  3   x3   x3 <NA>
 4:  4 <NA>   x4   x4
 5:  5 <NA> <NA>   x5
 6:  6 <NA> <NA>   x6
 7:  7   x7   x7 <NA>
 8:  8   x8 <NA>   x8
 9:  9   x9   x9 <NA>
10: 10  x10  x10  x10
```

I need to create column, that indicates combinations value of presence in columns `col1`, `col2` and `col3` by their colnames.
Expected output is provided below:

```
    ID        features
 1:  1 col1:col2:col3
 2:  2      col1:col2
 3:  3      col1:col2
 4:  4      col2:col3
 5:  5           col3
 6:  6           col3
 7:  7      col1:col2
 8:  8      col1:col3
 9:  9      col1:col2
10: 10 col1:col2:col3
```

The `features` column reflects in which combination the corresponding `ID` is present in `table1`. How can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `base R`, it can be used `apply()`:

```
#Code
table1$Var <- apply(table1[,-1],1,function(x) paste0(names(x)[!is.na(x)],collapse = ':'))
```

Output:

```
table1
    ID col1 col2 col3            Var
 1:  1   x1   x1   x1 col1:col2:col3
 2:  2   x2   x2 <NA>      col1:col2
 3:  3   x3   x3 <NA>      col1:col2
 4:  4 <NA>   x4   x4      col2:col3
 5:  5 <NA> <NA>   x5           col3
 6:  6 <NA> <NA>   x6           col3
 7:  7   x7   x7 <NA>      col1:col2
 8:  8   x8 <NA>   x8      col1:col3
 9:  9   x9   x9 <NA>      col1:col2
10: 10  x10  x10  x10 col1:col2:col3
```

Or using `tidyverse` functions:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Code
new <- table1 %>% pivot_longer(-ID) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(val=paste0(name[!is.na(value)],collapse = ":"))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 2
      ID val           
   <int> <chr>         
 1     1 col1:col2:col3
 2     2 col1:col2     
 3     3 col1:col2     
 4     4 col2:col3     
 5     5 col3          
 6     6 col3          
 7     7 col1:col2     
 8     8 col1:col3     
 9     9 col1:col2     
10    10 col1:col2:col3
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using `data.table`, you can do:

```
table1[, .(features = paste(names(table1)[-1][!is.na(.SD)], collapse = ":")), 
    ID]
##     ID       features
##  1:  1 col1:col2:col3
##  2:  2      col1:col2
##  3:  3      col1:col2
##  4:  4      col2:col3
##  5:  5           col3
##  6:  6           col3
##  7:  7      col1:col2
##  8:  8      col1:col3
##  9:  9      col1:col2
## 10: 10 col1:col2:col3
```

Or you can `melt` the data and then aggregate using `paste`:

```
melt(table1, "ID", na.rm = TRUE)[, .(features = paste(variable, collapse = ":")), ID]
```